# django-hstore on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, psycopg2, hstore

I've got a Django (v 1.3.3) project deployed on Heroku (cedar stack).  It uses the recommended dj_database_url for configuring settings.DATABASES.  Everything works great (to this point).

However, I want to start using [django-hstore](https://github.com/jordanm/django-hstore) for part of the application.  According to the docs, you have to change the database engine in settings.py to:

```
'ENGINE': 'django_hstore.postgresql_psycopg2',
```

As a result, in my settings.py file, I do the following:

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_hstore.postgresql_psycopg2'
```

Everything works fine for me, locally.  And my models that have hstore fields work great (values are dictionaries).

However, when I deploy to Heroku, the database engine gets reset/overridden to:

```
ENGINE: 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
```

In an attempt at debugging it, I have put a print after setting the engine in my settings file.  Then, I run bash:

```
heroku run bash
```

and then:

```
python myapp/manage.py shell
```

when I run this, my print statement shows me the correct (desired) database settings with the desired engine (django_hstore.postgresql_psycopg2).  However, if I then do:

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings.DATABASES
```

I can see the database engine is no longer django_hstore, but set back to the normal (non-hstore) value.  And if I import one of my models and do a get to load an object, the value in the hstore field is a string, and any attempt to access a key will throw and error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Please keep in mind that this works find locally.  But, after deploying to heroku, any attempt at accessing values as dictionaries throws the TypeError above.

My questions are:

- Does anyone know why my engine is getting overridden?  And if so, how do I fix this?

or

- Is there another way to use the hstore field with Django 1.3.3 that might not require having to change the engine (and therefore be a bit more Heroku friendly)

Comment: What did you end up working out?  I'm looking at using HStore w/ Django & Heroku and am wary of this pitfall before jumping into it.

Answer (score 2):

[SQLAlchemy 0.8](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) includes utility methods that can be used to create a [custom model](http://justcramer.com/2008/08/08/custom-fields-in-django/) for handling the conversion between Python `dict` and Postgres `hstore`.

```
from django.db import models
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.hstore import _parse_hstore, _serialize_hstore

class HStoreField (models.TextField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HStoreField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return value
        return _parse_hstore(value)

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
        if value is None:
            return None
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value
        return _serialize_hstore(value)

    def db_type (self, connection):
         return "hstore"
```

This model is portable, but if you want to run queries based on hstore keys or values you'll have to write them in raw SQL.

I use an SQLite in-memory database for running tests, which works fine as long as you use the `text` type for non-PostgreSQL backends:

```
    def db_type (self, connection):
        from django.db import connection
        if connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'] == \
            'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2':
            return "hstore"
        else:
            return "text"
```

Comment: For what it‘s worth I am using a variation on this in a Django 1.5 and it appears to be working. I had to add an incantation to make it work smoothly with South.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/niwibe/djorm-ext-hstore

Looks like this package was originally a fork of django-hstore and includes the same functionality, but has been updated to no longer require a custom Database backend which would appear to alleviate your problem.  (Note that some of the query syntax has changed in it).

As a bonus, the repo is maintained much more recently than the [original django-hstore](https://github.com/jordanm/django-hstore) you link to, which hasn't been touched in years... scary.

Comment: That's true. django-hstore doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, while djorm-ext-hstore is active.

Answer (score 1):

happy to tell you the new version 1.2.1 of django_hstore is out

Upgrade via pip and check the new official django-hstore github repository: https://github.com/djangonauts/django-hstore